# Azure DevOps deployment pipeline: update appsettings.json with new objects

Tags: azure

I'm trying to configure a set of deployment pipeline in Azure DevOps for deploying an ASP.NET core 2.2 application to local servers (not azure).

I'm hitting a wall with something that seem trivial to me: I'm trying to add a set of objects the the appsettings.json files.

I tried to use the JSON variable substitution option if the IIS Application deployment task but it only works to adjust existing entries in the appsettings.json files, it doesn't seem to be able to add any new one.

I need to add these entries (not update them) because one of them is mapped to a dictionary that will have many more entries in production  that in dev.

I also tried to use [magic-chunk](https://github.com/sergeyzwezdin/magic-chunks) but it seems to have the same problem: if the JSON path does not exists, it crashes with an ReflectionTypeLoadException error.

Answer (score 0):

For lack of a better option, I've used the [File Creator](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eliostruyf.build-task) extension to push the whole file in the pipeline.